# Wrong encoding of Russian, Portuguese etc. text

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, collation

I have a table where I store some text labels. Originally it was built using latin_swedish_ci (default) collation.

Now I need to support additional languages, like Russian. I havbe two pages that consume those labels. One shows them fine, despite the fact that the table is still with latin collation and NOT utf8_generic_ci, however the other page is still showing garbage. When I view source it looks like this:

\u00d0\u00a4\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00bb\u00d1\u0152\u00d1\u201a\u00d1\u20ac\

Both pages have:

```
 <META http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

What am I missing?

---

UPDATE:

I don't know why, and how it works, but I ended-up adding the following before my query inserting/updating and before rendering on the page and it fixed all my problems:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

If you too wasted enough time trying meta tags and headers, give this solution a whirl.

Comment: You need to set the charset of PHP, HTML, database/tables and the connection object to the same thing, in your case UTF-8. To avoid broken characters, *everything* needs to be the same charset.

Comment: Ouff, your demo link (http://www.usabilitest.com/uxXQAzq) to my opinion (I don't really know Russian) shows it correctly. And, if I remember right, you are having the situation where both Portuguese and Russian should be supported. _Everything_ in UTF-8 would be best in this case.

Comment: BTW, this link could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756877/how-to-convert-latin1-swedish-ci-data-into-utf8-general-ci

Comment: The instructions are shown correctly, because I pull them froma  different table. Once you dismiss the modal, the containers have it in EN, PT and RU. I converted table to utf8_general_ci, but still see the values all messed-up, appearing like this: Ð­Ñ‚Ð¾ Ð±Ñ‹ÑÑ‚Ñ€Ñ‹Ð¹ Ñ‚ÐµÑÑ. I even added the following header to my PHP file where I insert/update db: header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"); but to no avail... Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* use the `mysql_*` interface; switch to `mysqli_*`.

You probably wanted something like `Фил...`?

There are probably two wrong to get that mess.

The `meta` tag is good; the `SET NAMES utf8` is needed.

But probably you have stored garbage in the table.  So, let's look at the table:  `SELECT col, hex(col) FROM tbl...`

For `Фил`, you should see hex of `D0A4D0B8D0BB`.  If you see `C390C2A4C390C2B8C390C2BB`, you have "double encoding".  Instead, it seems that somehow you got "unicode" instead of "utf8", and possibly from the "latin1" you started with.  Note how `D0 A4 D0 B8 D0 BB` shows up in my hex and in your `\u00d0...`?

If you can start over, do so:

- utf8 encoding in client
- `SET NAMES utf8`
- `CHARACTER SET utf8` on column/table
- `<meta charset=UTF-8>`

If you cannot start over, the let's see that `SELECT` I asked for; *maybe* I can find a way to salvage your data.