# Pasted text recorded in database with quotes replaced by "???" [PHP]

Tags: php, quotes

I used this code to insert text in my php database:

```
<p>
    <textarea id="uploader" style="
        width:860px;
        height:80px;
        font-size:16px;
        font-weight:300;
        outline:none;
        border:none;
        border-bottom:solid 1px #EDEDED;
        padding:20px"
    type="text"
    name="paragraph_two"
    placeholder="Paste the text here"></textarea>
</p>
```

Here is the PHP uploader:

```
if (!empty($_POST['paragraph_two']))  {
    $paragraph_two =  addslashes($_POST['paragraph_two']);
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO news (paragraph_two)
VALUES ('$paragraph_two')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    header('Location:../index.php?done');
} else {
    header('Location:../index.php?error');
}
```

Here is how I output the text:

```
$paragraph_two = stripslashes(utf8_decode(nl2br($donnees['paragraph_two'])));
echo $paragraph_two;
```

The problem is that when I paste text from other websites in the textarea and upload it to my database, the outputted text is not well encoded. The single quotes and double quotes are replaced by something like "??". When I write the text in the textarea by myself it works like a charm.

My database is set to `latin_swedish_ci`.

I tried to encode text in UTF8 before uploading it but it doesn't work. I've been investigating in this problem for 1 week now, I didn't find any solution. Can somebody explain me what happens ?

Comment: What's the code you use to contact the upload script and send it the text? You also mention the outputted text.  Where and how do you output the text?

Comment: Encoding text into UTF8 won't help if the database isn't also encoded in UTF8. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756877/how-to-convert-latin1-swedish-ci-data-into-utf8-general-ci

Comment: Also try mysqli_real_escape_string() as opposed to addslashes()

Comment: @BeetleJuice I used the form action attribute like this `<form method="POS" action='functions/upload.php'>`

Comment: @mulquin I just did as you told. I converted my database to UTF8. The problem still occurs !