# utf8_decode is not decoding ÃŸ (black diamonds �)

Tags: php, mysql

I am fixing a database (not whole, table by table), moving `latin1_swedish_ci` fields to `utf8_bin`, because it has a lot of special characters (german and spanish). Not all the characters are bad formated. So some fields are `á` and others are `Ã¡`.

### What I am trying

- **Step 1**: Duplicate table
- **Step 2**: Change collation to utf8 and motor to InnoDBand
- **Step 3**: PhpScript to update data

### Problem

- Black diamonds (�) utf_decoding some special chars.

## SQL QUERYS

### Old Table

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customers_old` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `last_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `first_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `customers_old` (`id`, `last_name`, `first_name`) VALUES
(1, 'Ã¡Ã©Ã­Ã³Ãº', 'GruÃŸe');

ALTER TABLE `customers_old`
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `customers_old`
    MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
```

### New table

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customers_new` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `last_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
    `first_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

INSERT INTO `customers_new` (`id`, `last_name`, `first_name`) VALUES
(1, 'Ã¡Ã©Ã­Ã³Ãº', 'GruÃŸe');

ALTER TABLE `customers_new`
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `customers_new`
    MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
```

## PHP SCRIPT

### UpdateCustomers

```
<?
# Classes
    include_once( "../db_functions.php" );
    $dbf = new DbFunctions();

# Functions
    function CheckStrangeCharacters( $string )
    {
        if ( strpos( $string, 'ã' ) !== false || strpos( $string, 'Ã' ) !== false ) 
        {
            $string = utf8_decode( $string );
        }

        return $string;
    }

# Load old customers
    $query = "SELECT * FROM customers_old";
    $customers = $dbf->Select( $query );

# Each customer
    for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $customers ); $i++ ) 
    { 
        # Assign variables
            $nv["id"]                       = $customers[$i]["id"];
            $nv["last_name"]                = $customers[$i]["last_name"];
            $nv["first_name"]               = $customers[$i]["first_name"];

        # Remove strange characters if contains ã or Ã
            $nv["last_name"]                = CheckStrangeCharacters( $nv["last_name"] );
            $nv["first_name"]               = CheckStrangeCharacters( $nv["first_name"] );

        # Update Reg
            $query = "UPDATE customers SET last_name = '" . $nv["last_name"] . "',  first_name = '" . $nv["first_name"] . "' WHERE id = " . $nv["id"];
            $response = $dbf->Update( $query );
        }
    }
?>
```

## RESULTS

### Old table data

```
| id |   last_name | first_name |
|  1 | 'Ã¡Ã©Ã­Ã³Ãº' |  'GrÃ¼ÃŸe' |
```

### New table data

```
| id | last_name | first_name |
|  1 |   'áéíóú' |      'Grü' |
```

### Expected New table data

```
| id | last_name | first_name |
|  1 |   'áéíóú' |    'Grüße' |
```

If you echo `first_name` at `utf8_decode` it will show `Grü�?e`

Comment: Why not something like `INSERT INTO ... SELECT CONVERT(table.col USING UTF8)` - do it right in the database ? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert

Comment: First time I see that. I will try. Thank you.

Comment: TL;DR � is not [black diamond](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25c6/index.htm). It is ['REPLACEMENT CHARACTER' (U+FFFD)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0fffd/index.htm). It normally reveals a prior encoding error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thaks to @CD001 (https://stackoverflow.com/users/886824/cd001) to make me look to another way.

Found a solution in stackoverflow ([How to convert latin1_swedish_ci data into utf8_general_ci?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756877/how-to-convert-latin1-swedish-ci-data-into-utf8-general-ci)):

```
INSERT INTO customers_new (customers_new.first_name)
SELECT convert(cast(convert(customers_old.first_name using latin1) as binary) using utf8)
    FROM customers_old
    WHERE customers_old.id = 1
```