# data UTF-8 to insert on latin1_swedish_ci table MYSQl

Tags: php, mysql, sql, utf-8, character-encoding

After many research I'm still stuck on a problem.

First of all,
I was trying to insert some data in a database by generating the query from a PHP file but that was not working.

So I try to execute manually the query on `PHPMyAdmin` and it worked. Then, I begun my research and the most possible explication that I found, is that my encoding isn't the same.

My informations are `UTF-8` and my table `latin1_swedish_ci` but a very bad problems appears, I can't modify the database. :(

So now,
I'm searching a way to convert UTF-8 to `latin1_swedish_ci` in my `PHP` file.

I hope someone could help to find a solution, or could orientate my research.

Here is my code

```
function insertGrp($rawData)
{
    //Format data form best use
    $data = self::formatFormData($rawData);
    $insertGrpReq ="INSERT INTO `fwsgup` (`KGROUP`, `KUSER`, `KDATES`, `FDATEE`, `PSPY`) VALUES ('";
    //First part of request
    $groups = $data["userGroup"];
    //Separator for concat
    $separator = "', '";
    //Instance of db
    $db = new DBInteract();
    //foreach group needed to be removed
    foreach($groups as $group)
    {       
        //converting dates for database
        $tmp = strtotime($group[1]);
        $startDate =date('Ymd', $tmp);

        $tmp = strtotime($group[2]);
        $endDate =date('Ymd', $tmp); 

        //DEBUG for see query
        //output example INSERT INTO `fwsgup` (`KGROUP`, `KUSER`, `KDATES`, `FDATEE`, `PSPY`) VALUES ('gAdmin', 'fana', '20170619', '20190619', '20171907133741faan');
        print($insertGrpReq.$group[0].$separator.$data["userInfo"]["userID"].$separator.$startDate.$separator.$endDate.$separator.date("YdmHis")."faan');</br>");
        //here's my problem
        $db->query($insertGrpReq.iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $group[0]).$separator.iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $data["userInfo"]["userID"]).$separator.iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $startDate).$separator.iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $endDate).$separator.iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", date("YdmHis")).iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", "faan"));
    }

}
```

Here's the table

`CREATE TABLE FWSGUP
(
   KGROUP varchar(16) NOT NULL,
   KUSER varchar(16) NOT NULL,
   KDATES int NOT NULL,
   FDATEE int,
   PSPY varchar(24),
   CONSTRAINT Q_CCVDPRD_FWSGUP_KGROUP_00001 PRIMARY KEY (KGROUP,KUSER,KDATES)
)`

Comment: I mix latin1_sweedish_ci with utf-8 all the time, do you have any special characters in your database?

Comment: What bad problems appear? Could you present them?

Comment: @HoogleyBoogley yes I got some è or é

Comment: @MinistryofChaps the problem is that i can't modify my database

Comment: @Jakob I understand you now, could you show us the code that is not working for you?

Comment: @Jackob That explains a lot of why it isn't working. Please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756877/how-to-convert-latin1-swedish-ci-data-into-utf8-general-ci

Comment: @HoogleyBoogley thanks for linking this post but in my example I don't have a special char that could fail the query

Comment: BEWARE -- certain after-the-fact conversion techniques only make things worse!  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SELECT HEX(col) ...` so we can see what you actually have in the table.

Answer (score 1):

[iconv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) will convert strings from one encoding to the other.

```
iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $text);
```

Comment: I tried it but it dosen't work is there an other way to convert it?

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you provide me with an example of what you are trying to convert?

Comment: I don't have error :( I put an example on the post

Comment: change the $insertGrpReq to 

"INSERT INTO fwsgup (KGROUP, KUSER, KDATES, FDATEE, PSPY) VALUES ('"

Comment: Same problem no error and dosen't work..

Comment: replace the last line of the loop this this

Comment: $output = $db->query($insertGrpReq.iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $group[0]).$separator.iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $data["userInfo"]["userID"]).$separator.iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $startDate).$separator.iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $endDate).$separator.iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", date("YdmHis")).iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", "faan"));

echo $output;

Comment: echo provide an error because the result is an array then I've replaced by print_r and i've got an empty array

Comment: Can you try running the raw sql directly in the database and see if you get an error doing it that way?

Comment: Any error the query is correct

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help about encoding but I found that encoding isn't a problem, A simple update works. It means that the problem is the build of the query